# Convert base 10 colors OR hex colors to ANSI colors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, colors, hex, ansi-escape

The title pretty much says it all. I need to know a way I can convert either base 10 colors OR hex colors to ANSI colors that I can use in the terminal (for example `\u001b[31m` which is red in ANSI colors).

Either a JavaScript solution or a JS library would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [ANSI Escape Codes](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#rgb-colors) I am seeing a way to use RGB colors in ANSI, so you can create a function that takes hex colors and converts them to RGB, and I'm assuming by base 10 colors you already mean RGB
So we can check to see if we have a hex color by seeing if the first character is a "#"

```
if (color.toString()[0] == "#") { /* then you have yourself a hex color, let's make it RGB*/ }
function hexToRGB(color) {
    color = color.toString();
    var r = parseInt(color.substring(1, 3), 16);
    var g = parseInt(color.substring(3, 5), 16);
    var b = parseInt(color.substring(5, 7), 16);
    return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}
```

So after that you will have your RGB (assuming your hex color is in the form of `#FFFFFF`)

Use this as a guide to take your RGB string and format it into an ANSI Escape Code:
[image: Use this as a guide to take your RGB string and format it into an ANSI Escape Code]

Answer (score 1):

There are several JS libraries that support ANSI rgb and hex colors:

- [ansis](https://github.com/webdiscus/ansis)
- [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk)

Usage examples:

```js
import ansis from 'ansis';

// using standard named 16 colors
ansis.red('some text')

// red text
ansis.rgb(200, 0, 0)('some text')

// bold orange text on grey background
ansis.hex('#FF4500').bgHex('#333').bold('some bold text')
```

Usage examples with imported colors and template literal syntax:

```js
import { red, green, hex } from 'ansis/colors';

// using standard named 16 colors
red`some text`

// bold orange text on grey background
hex('#FF4500').bgHex('#333').bold`some bold text`

// nested color strings
hex('#FF4500')`orange ${green.bold`my bold green text`} orange`;
```